# My HTML/PHP Mail Form Doesn't Work Which Used To Work Before

Tags: php, html, forms, email, smtp

So, I have hostinger server. It's a shared server. Before all my Php Forms worked like a charm. I have different sites and all worked fine. But one day I noticed, all stopped working. It says mail has been sent, but does not send any mail. I am not sure if the issue on server side or the code. Because same code used to work.

I am dropping a random code from one of my site. The file is mail.php.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];


$EmailTo = "example@gmail.com";
$Title = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Fields .= "Name: ";
$Fields .= $name;
$Fields .= "\n";

$Fields.= "Email: ";
$Fields .= $email;
$Fields .= "\n";

$Fields.= "Subject: ";
$Fields .= $subject;
$Fields .= "\n";

$Fields .= "Message: ";
$Fields .= $message;
$Fields .= "\n";


// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo,  $Title,  $Fields, "From:".$email);
```

Here I have replaced my main email and wrote example@gmail.com Just to hide the email id. In my website, it was my own email.

Comment: Post the `mail` function also. And is this your own server or paid service? If paid service, it's possible that the hosting company changed something or PHP mail() is disabled. Did you contact their support first?

Comment: It's paid server. No I did not contact them. Should I contact?

Comment: what should I ask them?